What is the replacement of `Get-AzEventGridSubscription -ResourceGroup -TopicName` in Az PowerShell 12.x
Running the following command
Get-AzEventGridSubscription -ResourceGroup $ResourceGroup -TopicName $EventGridTopic

in Az PowerShell 12.x, the command results in
cmdlet Get-AzEventGridSubscription at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
DomainName: 
Get-AzEventGridSubscription: Cannot bind argument to parameter 'DomainName' because it is an empty string.

even it works in Az PowerShell 11.x.
As No event grid domains to display shown in the Azure Portal and an empty string is not allowed, I have no idea what value to provide. I also failed to find how to migrate the call to the newer version (there is neither any guidance in the cmdlet docs, Release Notes, Migration Guide nor Upcoming Breaking Changes).
What is the correct way to list all subscriptions in 12.x?

There are some changes in Get-AzEventGridSubscription cmdlet between v11.6.0 and v12.1.0.
In v11.6.0 you don't need to set -DomainName when using -ResourceGroup and -TopicName:
Get-AzEventGridSubscription
   [-EventSubscriptionName <String>]
   [-ResourceGroupName <String>]
   [-TopicName <String>]
   [-IncludeFullEndpointUrl]
   [-ODataQuery <String>]
   [-Top <Int32>]
   [-DefaultProfile <IAzureContextContainer>]
   [<CommonParameters>]

But in v12.1.0 -DomainName is required when using -ResourceGroup and -TopicName:
Get-AzEventGridSubscription
   -ResourceGroupName <String>
   [-SubscriptionId <String[]>]
   -DomainName <String>
   -TopicName <String>
   [-Filter <String>]
   [-Top <Int32>]
   [-DefaultProfile <PSObject>]
   [-PassThru]
   [<CommonParameters>]


How can I determine what value to pass to the DomainName argument? I found no such information in the portal and when I open the Domains blade I get No event grid domains to display.

@alik use v11 or, as an alternative, use different options as specified in syntax.

Not really helpful. As per the original question, I was on the page, but failed to find the help there. There seems to be a lot of breaking changes in Event Grid's cmdlets between v11.x and v12.x where it is not trivial to migrate the scripts to the new version as they take a completely different set of arguments. I found no docs nor Upgrade notes explaining the changes or how to migrate; neither in docs for the cmdlets, nor for the REST API called by the cmdlets.
